# How to get string value using eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to execute a query using `eloquent`, however it returns me an `array`. What I want is to only get the `string value` of my query.

This is what I get

> [{"name":"hey"}] [{"name":"sdasdasd"}]

Here's my `eloquent` query:

```
 $categoryName = Category::select('name')->where('id', request('category'))->get();
 $subCategory = Subcategory::select('name')->where('id', request('subCat'))->get();
```

Comment: if you always get single value then use `first` in place of `get` . it will return single object

Comment: try with pluck eloquent

Comment: $titles = DB::table('roles')->pluck('title');

Comment: [{"name":"hey"}] [{"name":"sdasdasd"}] aren't arrays, they are instances of Collections which means that when you iterate over them, you can access their values using the `->name` syntax, rather than array syntax: `['name']` :) fyi

Comment: @party-ring Oh sorry I'm not good with terminologies. :) Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**as per the Laravel [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries)**

Retrieving A Single Row / Column From A Table
If you just need to retrieve a single row from the database table, you may use the first method. This method will return a single stdClass object:

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->first();

echo $user->name;
```

If you don't even need an entire row, you may extract a single value from a record using the value method. This method will return the value of the column directly:

```
$email = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->value('email');
```

so in your example maybe you need to do something like the following :

```
$subCategory = Subcategory::select('name')->where('id', request('subCat'))-> first();

echo $subCategory->name;
```

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of the native PHP kind of query. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to achive your goal.

**Solutions**

1. Use `pluck()`.

```php
$categoryName = Category::select('name')
                ->where('id', request('category'))
                ->pluck()
                ->first();
```

2. Use model properties.

```php
$categoryName = Category::find(request('category'))
                ->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the answer using

```
$name = DB::table('Category')->where('id','=',request('category'))->pluck('name')->first();

echo $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take only name then follow the below code.

```
$categoryName = Category::where('id', request('category'))->first()->name;
$subCategory = Subcategory::where('id', request('subCat'))->first()->name;

echo $categoryName;
echo $subCategory;
```

If you take all columns in a row follow the below code:

```
$categoryName = Category::where('id', request('category'))->first();
$subCategory = Subcategory::where('id', request('subCat'))->first();

echo $subCategory->name;
echo $categoryName->name;
```

I hope this i may help you.Try this.

Answer (score 0):

$name = Category::select('name')->where('id', request('category'))->take(1)->orderBy('id','asc')->first()->name;

echo $name;

OR

echo Category::select('name')->where('id', request('category'))->take(1)->orderBy('id','asc')->first()->name;