# Laravel 7 - Missing data (blank view)

Tags: php, laravel, iframe, eloquent, view

I am working with iframes and I am trying to compare user email with teacher email with eloquent. That would be the condition to list only the groups of that teacher, but in the index view the table appears empty, that means that only the names of the columns of the table appear, but not the groups of that teacher, although it does have several.

- This is my function

```
 

    public function index($id)
            {
                 $email = User::select('email')->where('id', $id)->get();
        
                $groups= DB::table('groups')
                ->join('teacher_group', 'grupo_profesor.idGrupo', '=', 'groups.idGrupo')
                ->join('teachers', 'teachers.idTeacher', '=', 'teacher_group.idTeacher')
                ->join('level_group', 'level_group.idGroup', '=', 'groups.idGroup')
                ->join('levels', 'levels.idLevel', '=', 'level_group.idLevel')
                ->join('courses', 'courses.idCourse', '=', 'levels.idCourse')
                ->join('programs', 'programs.idProgram', '=', 'courses.idProgram')
                ->where('teachers.email', '=', $email)
                ->paginate(10);
                 
            return view('teacherGroups.index', compact('groups','email'));
            }
```

- The sidebar button

```
    <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action small text-secondary" 
    onclick="crearTabAndIframe('TeacherGroups','teacherGroups');
    Loadiframe('{{ url('Groups/Teacher/'.auth()->user()->id)}}','ifrmTeacherGroups')">
    
         <i class="material-icons">list</i> @lang('menu.List')
    
    </button>
```

- This is the index view

```
     @foreach($groups as $group)   
        <tr>
            <td class="small text-center">{{$group->idGroup}}</td>
        
            <td class="small  text-center">{{$group->levelName}} {{$group->courseName}} {{$group->programName}}</td>
        
            <td class="small  text-center">{{$group->teacher_name}}</td>
            
            <td class="small  text-center">
                <div class="row small">
                    <div >
                        <!--VIEW-->
                        <button onclick="seeGroup({{$group->idGroup}})" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">
                            <i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Could it be because in the where condition with eloquent my $email variable somehow has to be in quotes because I'm comparing strings? but is it possible in eloquent? Although, I still have to point out that I tried a DB::select query, but it was also unsuccessful. However, if I directly put the email like this:

```
$groups= DB::table('groups')
            ->join('teacher_group', 'grupo_profesor.idGrupo', '=', 'groups.idGrupo')
            ->join('teachers', 'teachers.idTeacher', '=', 'teacher_group.idTeacher')
            ->join('level_group', 'level_group.idGroup', '=', 'groups.idGroup')
            ->join('levels', 'levels.idLevel', '=', 'level_group.idLevel')
            ->join('courses', 'courses.idCourse', '=', 'levels.idCourse')
            ->join('programs', 'programs.idProgram', '=', 'courses.idProgram')
            ->where('teachers.email', '=', 'example@gmail.com')
            ->paginate(10);
```

It works like this, but how do I compare the user's email with the teacher's email?

***Note: I already saw that the value that returns me with the

```
$email = User::select('email')->where('id', $id)->get();
```

it's this: `[{"email":"example@gmail.com"}]`

And if I use

```
$email = User::select('email')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

The value that returns me is this: `{"email":"example@gmail.com"}`

How do I get just the email?

Answer (score 0):

Ok basically i had to change this part

```
$email = User::select('email')->where('id', $id)->get();
```

For this

```
$email = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->value('email');
```

Because the value it returned to me was: `[{"email":"example@gmail.com"}]`

And now it just returns to me the email value. Like this

> example@gmail.com

Also the answers of this question helped me: [How to get string value using eloquent query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57786182/how-to-get-string-value-using-eloquent-query)